# How do I pivot and aggregate in Pandas based on consecutive rows with no change in two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, aggregate

Lets say I have the following data, and require the output shown below it.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'job_id': 1, 'employee': 'Joe', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 10)},
    {'job_id': 1, 'employee': 'Joe', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 11)},
    {'job_id': 2, 'employee': 'Joe', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 12)},
    {'job_id': 2, 'employee': 'Joe', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 13)},
    {'job_id': 1, 'employee': 'Joe', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 14)},
    {'job_id': 1, 'employee': 'Joe', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 17)},
    {'job_id': 2, 'employee': 'Jill', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 10)},
    {'job_id': 2, 'employee': 'Jill', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 11)},
    {'job_id': 1, 'employee': 'Jill', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 12)},
    {'job_id': 1, 'employee': 'Jill', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 13)},
    {'job_id': 3, 'employee': 'Jill', 'date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 14)}
]

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

output_data = [
    {'job_id': 1, 'employee': 'Joe', 'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 10), 'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 11)},
    {'job_id': 2, 'employee': 'Joe', 'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 12), 'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 13)},
    {'job_id': 1, 'employee': 'Joe', 'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 14), 'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 17)},
    {'job_id': 2, 'employee': 'Jill', 'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 10), 'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 11)},
    {'job_id': 1, 'employee': 'Jill', 'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 12), 'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 13)},
    {'job_id': 3, 'employee': 'Jill', 'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 14), 'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 14)}
]

output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_data)
```

Essentially, I have the table ordered by `employee`, and then by ascending `date`.  I need an aggregation of the start/end date of an employee on a given job.  A few things to note:

1. An employee can be on a job, move to another job, and then come back to the first job (see `Joe`- he was on Job 1, then 2, then back to 1).  This should show an entry for each transition (see his rows in the output data).
2. The employee might not be on a job for directly consecutive days (e.g.- 2 days off for the weekend), but if he was on a job for Thurs and Fri, then returned to it on Monday, that would all get one entry for Thurs-Monday.  Again, see `Joe` for his second set of days on Job 1.
3. An employee might only be on a job for one day.  In this case, the start_date and end_date should be the same day (see `Jill` on job 3).
4. An employee can only be on one job per day.

If it wasn't for the consecutive periods, I'd just to a pivot table, group by user/job, and aggregate by max and min date.  However, I am not sure how to do the group by, when I am looking for consecutive rows with the same `employee` and `job_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do so by two groupby:

```
# to mask the jobs chunks separately
s  = data_df.groupby('employee').job_id.apply(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum())

out_df = data_df.groupby(['employee', s]).agg({'job_id':'first', 'date':{'min','max'}})
```

gives:

```
                job_id        date            
                job_id         max         min
employee job_id                               
Jill     1           2  2019-06-11  2019-06-10
         2           1  2019-06-13  2019-06-12
         3           3  2019-06-14  2019-06-14
Joe      1           1  2019-06-11  2019-06-10
         2           2  2019-06-13  2019-06-12
         3           1  2019-06-17  2019-06-14
```

which can be changed to your form by:

```
out_df.columns = ['job_id', 'end_date', 'start_date']
out_df = out_df.reset_index(level=1,drop=True).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to do the trick.  Quick question though- what is going on with the job_id row index?  Or is that just some labeling wackiness due to the groupby?

Comment: That's come from `s`, whose name is `job_id`, not from `data_df`.

Comment: Ahh.. that makes sense (it was unfortunate that I used 1, 2, 3 for my ids, and had exactly 3 groups).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

My logic is similar with Quang Hoang, but I use 1 groupby due to the fact that you said your data already sorted by `employee` and `date`. Create groupID for continuous same `job_id` and save it as array `s`. I don't `groupby` here because in case 2 adjacent rows same `job_id`, different `employee` will be separated by the groupby of `employee` and `s` in next step

```
s = data_df.job_id.diff().ne(0).cumsum().values
```

Next, `groupby` on `employee`, 'job_id' and `s`. Call `agg` with `first`, `last` on `date and reset_index to put back columns and`drop`unwanted column. Finally,`rename` columns to appropriate names.

```
data_df.groupby(['employee', 'job_id', s], sort=False).date.agg(['first', 'last']) \
       .reset_index().drop('level_2', 1) \
       .rename(columns={'first': 'start_date', 'last': 'end_date'})

Out[1283]:
  employee  job_id  start_date    end_date
0      Joe       1  2019-06-10  2019-06-11
1      Joe       2  2019-06-12  2019-06-13
2      Joe       1  2019-06-14  2019-06-17
3     Jill       2  2019-06-10  2019-06-11
4     Jill       1  2019-06-12  2019-06-13
5     Jill       3  2019-06-14  2019-06-14
```

---

**Note**: I also test the sample data having 2 adjacent rows with different `employee`, but same `job_id`. It still works

```
Sample:
In [1289]: data_df
Out[1289]:
         date employee  job_id
0  2019-06-10      Joe       1
1  2019-06-11      Joe       1
2  2019-06-12      Joe       2
3  2019-06-13      Joe       2
4  2019-06-14      Joe       1
5  2019-06-10     Jill       1
6  2019-06-11     Jill       1
7  2019-06-12     Jill       2
8  2019-06-13     Jill       2
9  2019-06-14     Jill       3


s = data_df.job_id.diff().ne(0).cumsum().values
data_df.groupby(['employee', 'job_id', s], sort=False).date.agg(['first', 'last']) \
       .reset_index().drop('level_2', 1) \
       .rename(columns={'first': 'start_date', 'last': 'end_date'})

Out[1290]:
  employee  job_id  start_date    end_date
0      Joe       1  2019-06-10  2019-06-11
1      Joe       2  2019-06-12  2019-06-13
2      Joe       1  2019-06-14  2019-06-14
3     Jill       1  2019-06-10  2019-06-11
4     Jill       2  2019-06-12  2019-06-13
5     Jill       3  2019-06-14  2019-06-14
```